# KNEX / SQLite handling dates

Tags: javascript, sqlite, knex.js

I came across a weird problem and I need some help there :

I have a Knex connection to create a simple memory Sqlite db with ne table : planning

on my planning table I have a dateTime column such as :

```
    table.dateTime("reminder").notNullable();
```

Lets say I create one record :
the reminder value is "2021-01-01T10:00:00.000Z"

Query example (Knex debug log):

```
console.log
{
  method: 'raw',
  sql: "SELECT * from planning where reminder >= '2022-01-01T10:00:00.000Z'",
  bindings: [],
  options: {},
  __knexQueryUid: 'jJOXgREO6H9iXWfeeQP9o'
}
```

no matter the method to query this date, I always get unexpected results, this one above returns me 1 line but shouldn't
I tried Knex functions .where ; .whereBetween ... passing date objects in parameters... same.

```
var queryResults = await knex.from('planning').whereBetween('reminder',['2019-01-01','2022-01-01']).select();
```

returns 0 line

```
var queryResults = await knex.from('planning').select();
```

returns 1 line as expected

Any idea ?

EDIT :
Added sample data :
My unit test inserts data like that (and it works) :

```
await knex("planning").insert([ { reminder: new Date("2020-01-01 09:00"), subject : "Have a breakfast" }
```

console.log of a selected row prints :

```
{ id: 1, reminder: 'Wed Jan 01 2020 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale)', subject:'Have a breakfast' }
```

Comment: Post sample data of your dates.

Comment: Edited to add data

Comment: Make sure that you are handling timezones correctly. It does not seem like you do.

Comment: How would you handle timezones correctly with knex ? inserting 2020-01-01 et and selecting 2020-01-01 in the same code should share the same timezone and thus working, am I wrong ?